Unable to add request-header to POST request
I am hitting the API by using payload and in headers giving Content-Type : 'application/json' still in browser in request headers I'm seeing Content-Type : 'text/plain'
Because of that in the backend I am getting payload in Content-Type : 'text/plain'
export const abctrigger = (payload , signal) => {
  Return fetch (API_URL, {
    method: post,
    Signal: signal
    Body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    headers: {
      Content-Type : 'application/json'
    }
  })
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((response) => {
      return respon se;
    })
}
 

I want to Change request headers to  to Content-Type : 'application/json'

I would expect this code to produce at least one error, not to successfully send an AJAX request with or without the expected header.  There are a variety of syntax errors here.

The hyphen '-' in the property name probably causes the issue.
Try this:
headers: {
  "Content-Type": 'application/json'
}

Instead of this:
headers: {
  Content-Type : 'application/json'
}

And check your IDE settings, because with ms-code the later gives an error:
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","


Ski the above solutions is not working for me.  Also when I tried in unsecured browser the in request headers I'm getting  expected (content-type : 'application/json') but in normal browser I'm content-type is getting changed to 'plain/text'

try this:
export const abctrigger = (payload, signal) => {
  return fetch(API_URL, {
    method: 'POST', // Corrected method casing
    signal: signal, // Corrected comma
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json' // Corrected headers format
    }
  })
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((response) => {
    return response;
  });
};

I made 3 changes, exluding the post, that may be a variable, you forgot a comma and to round Content-Type with ''.

and 4th: you made Return -> return haha
